# Can I choose what time of day email notifications should be sent?

Tags: feature-request, email-notification

The email notifications are sent in the same time of the subscriptions?

I would like to choose the period (morning, afternoon, night) or the interval (6:00-9:00, 9:00-12:00, 12:00-15:00, etc) at which to receive them.

Sometimes I ignore the notifications because are sent in bad times.

Comment: Currently you may not. It would really be meaningful for me too to be able to choose the time, now I get them at 9.30 a.m., the worst possible time. I usually don't even have time to read the questions in the morning.  Also the time choice should take into account the user timezone (I'm GMT+1)

Comment: @rene: Why close this post; I'd rather close the newer one.

Comment: @Werner I considered that but I found the newer question more detailed. There is no rule that newer questions should be closed against older ones

Comment: @rene - So, original poster checks not been asked before, asks a question which is not a dupe. Another user X time later does not search or did but bad search and found nothing, and makes a new question which is a dupe. Surely the first one in has rights if they are "truly" duplicated? Original is not a dupe of anything, the *newer* one is the one which *created* the duplicate. (am discussing, not arguing)

Comment: @James I acted in the spirit of [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha) that is basically advising to choose the better question to stay open.

Comment: @rene k thanks. Disagree with that/Shog. Someone could have put a lot of effort into the original, and users deciding which is better is not really cricket. I'd raise a question but it'll just get the same old fluff. Cheers