# Why questions deleted by owner are not marked as "deleted by owner"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I saw many times at SO, and finally decided to ask, why questions deleted by owners are not marked as *"deleted by owner"*? One [recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195523/how-to-check-a-string-element-of-an-array-after-using-split):

[image]

In fact, I don't know how to consider my question. I believe there might be a reason for such behaviour, however I didn't find any clear explanation on Meta (if it exists, just close the question by duplication).

Nevertheless, I'd prefer to see *"deleted by owner"* instead of name repetition.

Comment: But is the OP the _owner_ of the post? Seeing as all content on SE is CC?

Comment: In that case there's a bug when one deletes ones answer @Oded; it shouldn't say "deleted by owner". I'm with this; it's extremely minor, but the behaviour should be consistent... it's also a bit like the OP approving an edit from a UI. Why can _one_ person successfully delete a post? It makes sense if it's rendered in the same way as answers.

Comment: @Oded Agreed with Ben's comment. Personally deleted answers are marked with *"deleted by owner"*, so possibly CC is not the main point here.

Comment: @hims056 This question is not a duplicate of that, it is vice versa according to the date of posting. I have asked this question on 7 January 2013, while that question was asked on 18 August 2013.

Comment: @VisioN posting dates of the duplicates don't matter, see eg [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/165773)

Comment: @gnat OK. Then which criteria have you used for identifying my question to be a duplicate? Both don't have a valid an answer as far as I see.

Comment: @VisioN hard to tell; per my understanding, when there is no clear and strong preference, dupe direction is determined quite randomly. It probably helps that, as opposed to other kinds of question closures, [duplicates are considered respectable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204526/165773 "as discussed eg here") (I for one feel 100% fine when my own questions, or questions I answered are dupe-closed)