# Inconsistency in which migrations count as "rejected"

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, migration, migration-rejection

Questions which have been migrated and then closed as *duplicates* count as "rejected" in the migration stats even though they aren't marked as rejected on the posts themselves.

Specifically, in the [migration stats](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) page on [Science Fiction & Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com), I see this:

[image: "66% rejected"]

But of the three questions migrated from Movies & TV in the last 90 days, the two [which](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/71579/27759) were [closed](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/71573/27759) were closed as *duplicates* and so the migrations weren't rejected. The migration stats page on M&TV bears this out:

[image: M&TV screencap with none rejected]

**TL;DR: questions migrated and then dupe-closed show as "rejected" in the target site's stats even though they aren't.**

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202188/migration-stats-not-consistent-between-sites