# Change message added to duplicates so that it works even when the closed question was asked earlier

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, moderator-messages

It [has been determined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/242800) in certain conditions, an old question can be marked as a duplicate of a newer one.
However the explanation message still says duplicates are for newer questions.

[image: screen shot of the text box]

In this case, the part: "This question has been ***asked before*** ..." should be changed, because some questions have already been marked as duplicate of a newer one.

Answer (score 3):

Now that I look at it, I find the next section of the message [wordy|repetitive|dense|the word "answers" shows up too many times, too close together] as well.

"This question has been asked elsewhere. If the answers there do not fully..." (identical from that point forward)

Comment: I'm Ok with your proposal. Please note that I can't accept your answer as you don't have the necessary rights...

Comment: @user2284570 I don't have the necessary rights? What does that mean? It's fine if you don't accept it; I'd like if you wait for more answers, personally; that way we get more input. Just curious what you mean.

Comment: That you can't implement the feature of course! :)

Comment: @user2284570 There isn't a requirement that I be a Stack Exchange team member to accept my answer. If you agree that much, accept it. If the question gets enough traffic, somebody from the team will see it and decide if it's worth implementing. (This is where I believe leaving the question unsolved for a little while could generate more traffic)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that it means "asked before now" rather than "asked before this question".

I don't see a driving need for change.

Comment: You didn't understand: Imagine you ask a question. Later someone ask a question, with the same topic. Your question (which is older) is closed as a duplicate. The message you got with the duplicate tell your question is newer than the other one, whereas this is the contrary (your closed question is older than the opened one).

Comment: I understood perfectly. But, okay, what should it be _changed to_?

Comment: Why not something starting like : "This question covers the same content as an another one....". Note : I'm bad at finding good sentences like this one.