# Can we add Top Questions to our careers page, just as we have Top Answers?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

My [Careers profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/83003) allows me to add Top Answers that I've posted on Stack Exchange.  This is great; it lets prospective employers see example of my knowledge and expertise, my style of solutions and helping others, etc.

**Can we add the ability to also post Top *Questions* that we've asked, please?**

Questions are just as valuable as answers.  No employer (should) expect to get an employee that knows everything. The way you address what you don't know, the kind of question you ask, the research or approaches you've taken to tackling a problem before you resort to asking others are all very useful information about the kind of employee someone will be.

In fact, putting on my interview hat for a moment, I would prefer to employ someone who knows less about an area but is intelligent when learning and tackling what they don't know, than someone who knows a lot but cannot handle problems.

There are a few questions of mine that I think show my approach to problem-solving, or my approach to ending ignorance, in a good light.  I'd like to showcase them!

Comment: After asking (despite searching) I find there's [a duplicate.](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/83003)  However, it's two years old, no action despite upvotes, and I think is one is a *better-asked question* with *more rationale*. Moderators, please merge if you wish, but please compare the questions before voting to close.

Comment: I would agree to that. Asking a good question on a job relevant topic can expose a similar understanding of a topic as a good answer. I most say that I learned a lot from answering on SO when a question offered me a perspective on a problem that I never thought about.

Comment: Closed as dupe because although this is more text, it's the same content, as is shown in the answers to the other question.  Additionally, you should expand the other question with an answer containing your reasoning, not another question.

Comment: @NickLarsen: the question material does not include much of the above (eg, why is it important? What's the employer perspective? Etc) and has no action. Is marking it as a duplicate of a Q with less info and less rationale that has had no effect/action after years useful?

Comment: Yes, you should support the question with an upvote and add your thoughts as an answer.

Comment: @NickLarsen ["If the new question is a better question or has better answers, then vote to close the *old* one as a duplicate of the *new* one."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha) This is a much better question, as I think you indicated - after all, answers may contribute (and they're not (IMO) as high-quality as this question), and that question material itself is worse. Don't forget the question and answers have all been ignored; they're not useful as-is, either.