# Allow the original poster the option to apply a rejected suggested edit on their own post

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

This *isn't* to change to the current rejection process or review queue in any way.

---

There was recently a [rejected edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7584985) on one of my answers.

It was correct to reject from the reviewer's point of view, because variable names in code were changed, however, the edit would have been beneficial to the post in this case, and I would have liked the suggested edit to have been accepted.

I edited my answer and manually added the rejected suggested changes myself. On this occasion it was a small edit, but this would be quite time consuming if it was a more substantial edit.

It would be useful if we had a feature where a user can approve/improve an edit on *their **own** question or answer* which was previously rejected by community review.

Ideally, there would also be the option to <kbd>Edit & Approve</kbd> so we can change any bits if necessary.

Perhaps (for example) an option in the Suggested Edits history where only the OP, and maybe moderators, can select to approve or improve a rejected edit.

OPs can currently approve suggested edits, overruling the review queue, so this would just be an extension of that - being able to approve *after* 3 users have rejected.

Comment: @ShadowWizard This is not a duplicate, although that question states that it can't be done, why don't we just make it so it can be done? (I just edited the question to clarify)

Comment: No, this is still far from being written as feature request.

Comment: @ShadowWizard alright, I just edited the post to make it a little more like a feature reques

Comment: Voted to re-open. The other is asking *how* to re-approve a rejected edit which has simply been confirmed in the answer - the other Q is *finished*. This is *proposing* we allow being able to do so. I agree, this is not a great feature request, although that doesn't mean it's a dupe of another question just because of the same subject.Let's just improve this one.

Comment: @Jojodmo I've made a *huge* change to your question. I believe I have encapsulated what you want, but please review it, change whatever as necessary, or roll back if you disagree with most of it etc. I noticed you were last seen 2 mins ago, so hopefully you'll see this before other users.

Comment: @James Thanks, that makes the question into way more of a feature request. I added some more ideas, but I didn't really change too much of what you added.

Comment: Yup, @James did a good job. Would have reopened myself if I'd spot earlier.

Comment: @ShadowWizard ^^

Comment: @ShadowWizard Shouldn't that question be closed as a duplicate of this one? It was posted earlier, but [this one has answers, while the other doesn't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/238826) making it more useful to future readers

Comment: @Jojodmo not sure, none of the answers here are official, so it's no big deal.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ accidentally tagged the wrong person...  ^^

Comment: No I meant to ping him - I knew you'd be pinged anyways. I see now there was no point though, because I forgot @ShadowWizard doesn't have a [tag:feature-request] gold badge...yet :P

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ huh, but I'm really close to that badge! :-D

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Oh, I meant to say that I tagged the wrong person. I was trying to tell you about the above comment that says that the other post should be marked duplicate of this one (or they should be merged), because the other one has less community input.

Comment: @Jojodmo Ahh... Whoops! However my reply would be the same as Shadow's!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be integrated into the revision history of a post. Here is the [revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/252913/revisions) of your question.

Something like this?

> [image]

This could be visible to anyone in my opinion, since suggested edits can be seen too.

Comment: Are you saying to have "reject suggested edits" in edit history? Revision history is for actual edits which have occurred, not "attempted" edits IMO, and given there may be *various/numerous* rejected edits on any given Q or A, the edit history could get cluttered and become less useful.

Comment: Indeed, it can get cluttered. It has also some positive effect. It is easier to see people editing numerous times. It might also help diagnose edit patterns.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Maybe rejected ones could be hidden automatically, and you can click something to make them show? Kind of like displaying deleted posts on profiles

Comment: @Jojodmo: Why not. Seems a good idea. Maybe show a line between to show there is something to be made visible.

Comment: To solve the cluttering issue, the rejected edits could be combined, and could be shown like `6 suggested edits rejected.` `show rejected edits`. On larger posts, I would assume there has to be a lot of rejected edits, which would clutter the revision history if they weren't combined...

Comment: Good idea.  I think @Jojodmo's suggestion should be edited into the answer.  I'm voting up on the strength of his suggested modification to the proposal.

Answer (score 4):

While this will be *very* useful feature to have, I don't think it's likely to be used very frequently, so I think we should keep it simple.

I suggest a simple *text link* located in the review history page to approve rejected edits.

The link should only be visible to the OP of the question or answer (and moderators) as a way to overrule if the final decision was rejected.

Example:

[image: apply-rejected-edits]

---

---

Putting rejected edits in the Revision History is ok on face value, and would cater for this feature request (PatrickHofman's answer).
But this would mix different data together, as the Revision History is for "edits" - and rejected edit suggestions are not technically "edits" as they were rejected (no edit took place).

The history of rejected edits is not really useful, certainly not alongside *actual* Q or A edit history.
For monitoring if users have multiple rejections, the data should be collated elsewhere (i.e. don't try to use Revision history for too many things, it has it's own single purpose).

Comment: Are edit suggestions still shown in notifications once rejected? Otherwise there's no easy way for most post owners to get to them at all, or even know they're present.