# What if a new question, that is a duplicate of an older one, gets an answer but not older one?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

This may look similar to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha/147651#147651). But it isn't as in that question; the problem was that both were similar questions and one (the new one) was better than the other (older one). So which one should marked for closing? But here both the questions are **same**.

I recently answered a question, which was a duplicate of already-asked one, but it did not have any accepted (or good) answer. And somehow I didn't notice the older one and my answer on newly asked question got upvotes. Now I saw the same older question, but didn't have an answer, so I posted the answer of the newly-asked question there, and it became active.

**I can't close the older one as the newly one isn't a *better* than the older one; both are probably the same as I read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha/147651#147651)**

**What should I do in that case? Should I mark the older question as a duplicate in favor of the new one or what?**

---

[Older Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330593/browser-is-not-displaying-the-php-output-or-errors/887839?noredirect=1#comment1387045_887839)

[Newer Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887612/php-errors-are-not-showing-in-browser-only-page-goes-blank/887620#887620)