# If we had flagged a question as a duplicate of another, but it was actually the other way around, should I be one of the flaggers when it is closed?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

On [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com), I marked [How to 'linkify' plain text URLs (locally) on the Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/159980/154794) as a duplicate of [Make urls in plain text files into clickable links](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/283958/154794), because of the reasons described in the answers to [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/318692). However, it wasn't that way apparently and the other question that I marked as a duplicate was the original question.

Should I be listed for closing this a duplicate?

Comment: You're saying that you voted to close A as a dupe of B, and in the end B was closed as a dupe of A? And you never voted on B?

Comment: @KateGregory Correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Because it just doesn't work that way.

In essence, you let folk (a mod?, other users?) know that A was a duplicate of B - and while that push it into the review queue, there's clearly a dispute over whether you were right or not.

I wouldn't say [he chose poorly](https://youtu.be/Ubw5N8iVDHI)<sup>1</sup>, but you didn't choose well either. It's fine. No one's going to really blame you (unless this was a review queue - and they don't test you on dupes as far as I know). I'd even go as far as saying it's one of the few VERY subjective things SE is fine with.

I *would* not say you voted that way, when you voted another way.

<sub>1: Yeah, I love that movie too much.</sub>

Comment: This answer, unlike the other, actually explains. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 4):

You voted to close A as a dupe of B, and in the end B was closed as a dupe of A. And you never voted on B. Therefore I would **not** expect to see you listed in the close-voters for B.

Do you?

Comment: Yes, I would, actually.

Comment: Can you explain why? You did not vote to close B. You expressed (on A) an opinion about the sameness of A and B but it's not a transitive opinion. For example specific questions are often closed as dupes of generals but you could never close the general as a dupe of the specific.