# How to handle well-formulated duplicates vs bad original question

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

## Problem

I came across [one of those questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225371/split-string-between-character) that must have been asked before. While searching for the same question on SO, I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842264/r-split-string-by-symbol), which asks essentially the same thing. So far, so good.

I couldn't bring it over me to flag a well-formulated and high quality question as a duplicate of a question that is clearly inferior in terms of clarity, even though the core of the question is equivalent.

## Options

Now there are three options, in my opinion:

1. Not flagging and ignoring the dupe
2. Flagging the new question as a dupe
3. Thinking of the quality of SO, it may even make sense to flag the initial question as a duplicate of the new question!

All three options seem unfitting and wrong for different reasons. Please note that this question is *not* about whether the two questions in my example are actually regarded as dupes or not.

My question is: What would be the appropriate behaviour to handle a situation like this?

## Edit

This question does *not* focus on how to handle dupes, that arise as a result of the original question being outdated and/or requires new, updated answers (this was dealt with in this [meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha)). The issue here is purely about the quality of the original post.