# Progress background of gold badges in profile is barely noticable

Tags: bug, status-deferred, profile-page, accessibility, badge-progress

The difference between page background color and progress on golden badges is so miniscule that I find it hard to see it at all. I see progress on bronze and silver badges just fine, but the contrast of gold badges is so small that I need to check numbers to know where to look.

[image: Progress badge colors]

My sight is far from perfect and I'm protanomalous colorblind, but I don't think this affects the contrast enough. Let's do the math.

```
Bg color   R   G   B   H    S    L
page     255 255 255   0   0% 100%
bronze   209 166 132  26  46%  67%
silver   180 184 188 210   6%  72%
gold     255 250 230  48 100%  95%
```

The lightness value of bronze and silver badge progress backgrounds is around 70%, while lightness of gold is 95%, which is displayed on pure white background with 100% lightness. This is probably a mistake as numbers are clearly inconsistent.

This applies to all websites, both to badges displayed directly in profiles and to the popup for choosing a badge to track.

P.S. Even if protanomaly affects the contrast, it's one of the weakest types of color blindness, so people with other types of color blindness will be affected even more. Also slight differences in contrast are very dependent on monitor settings. Almost nobody has perfectly calibrated monitors.

**[Edit]** While this question turned out to be a dupe, it's higher quality than the first one, has more info and more upvoted already, so I'd rather close the other way.

**[Edit 2]** Considering this question is [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) in [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) and the other one is [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), I find it counter-productive to close this question instead of the other one ([who was first doesn't matter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643)).

Comment: If it's a small comfort it's just as bad for people with perfect vision. It is beneficial to use [NCS](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_ncol.asp?color=C66,%200.21,%200.58) to specific colors based on perception (rather than RGB, which is percentage of primary colors). This [NCS Color Chart Website](https://www.e-paint.co.uk/NCS_1950_colour_chart.asp) could assist you to pick two colors which are easier for ***you*** to view; though [color blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness#Rights_of_the_color_blind) affects people differently, and thus isn't protected in the USA.

Comment: They could use [SVG Patterns](https://philiprogers.com/svgpatterns/#honeycomb) such as [Honeycomb](https://jsbin.com/hucazo/embed?html,output) or checkerboard which would use different shades instead of only light yellow for the background; equally enhancing contrast for everyone, regardless of sightedness.

Comment: I just really fail to see a problem in this or the other question. I'm about to turn 60, but I can clearly see progress on the gold badges, both here and in my user. I did see that the other question said something about different browsers, but I tried several browsers, and I have no problem seeing the gold progress bar. It may be that people with trouble seeing it really just need to adjust their monitors.

Comment: Another possible reason here could be a incorrectly calibrated display. If your contrast or gamma is set too low, it may look less clear than it should.

Comment: This looks like a monitor issue indeed. I barely see the difference on either of my desktop monitors (and it's close to nonexistent on one), but it's more clear on my mobile phone of all things. Anyway, expecting everyone to have a perfectly calibrated monitor isn't reasonable. Futhermore, color blindness charts from Wikipedia suggest that faint yellow can be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

[ankii](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337477/269301) has a great idea by making the progress more clear.

However, it would clash with the current horizontal lay-out. How about rotating it around a bit instead?

[image: Like this]

By increasing the vertical space per tracker only a bit, a slider of sorts can be added to the existing bars:

[image: Very, very rough sketch]

Comment: We could even make it completely optional, to put there only for people indicating with a checkbox in their profile they want a colour-blind-friendly version of the site. This change could be the start of a lot more of such functions.

Answer (score 0):

A vertical bar that stands out can be used at the end of the progress. So the finish of the progress so far would stand out from the rest of the two colors, yellow and white.

[image]

In the second example, there is a circle. In the fifth one, there is a unique oval. We can have a vertical line.

Comment: You could even tilt those bars 90 degrees to keep them in the format we already have.

Comment: It is not a photo I own.. Let me check if html can do it..

Comment: A bit of cropping/rotating in paint would do, wouldn't it?

Comment: I can do that, but the photo comes from here https://support.visme.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Progress-bar-vertical.png Have you seen the markdown ?

Comment: How about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmhU2.png)?

Comment: I am neutral towards this.. Propose an edit if you wish :)

Comment: I'll write a small answer referring to your answer, let the devs figure out which *they* prefer.

Comment: I just wanted to show what the end of the bar will look like, whether horizontal or vertical.  I didn't say that it should be vertical.