# Description of the "Flag as duplicate" doesn't match official staff reply

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, information-display

I know I'm not the only person noticing inconsistencies in the description since it started

- [Should we change the description of "Duplicate of"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225174/364217)
- [Duplicate explanation should encourage improvement of original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166525/364217)

yet our concerns are different, I'm not looking to necessarily change the description and, even if we decide to go that way, we're addressing different parts of the description.

When flagging a post as duplicate, we can read the following information in the description

> This question has been *asked before **and** already has an answer*.

[image: Flag > Duplicate]

From this description a question that's older than a newer one and has an answer cannot be marked as duplicate, and we know from fact that's not true

- [Old question marked as duplicate of a new question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315472/5675325)
- [Which question is the better reference for a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252929/5675325)
- [Should I flag a question as duplicate if it has received better answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251938/5675325)

Accordingly to [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/364217),

> If the new question is a *better question **or** has better answers*, then
>   vote to close the old one as a duplicate of the new one.

This saying, what Shog9 says can contradict what is present in the description.

What's right and what's wrong? Do we need to change the Duplicate flag description?

Comment: Your question could also benefit from the [tag:wording] tag, but I'm not sure which tag it should replace.

Comment: @Luuklag maybe the *vote-to-close* one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess we need to get rid of the "before" altogether, if that's not the reason for closing a question.

**"This question has been asked elsewhere and has a better description or answers."**

could be an option (**vote** for this answer if you like that). I've removed "and / or" and used just "or" for the sake of simplicity.

(It would also allow for closing as dupe even if the question didn't get answers yet, which I suppose would be an option if SE actually listened [to their users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165933/176060). Don't vote for this part, I'm just ranting)

Comment: That's an interesting take but it assumes a better question is a question with a better description, and i tend to believe it's more than that. After seeing there's really no agreement in that, raised once a question [How are we supposed to define what makes a question better?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338506/364217) but the community didn't think it was good fit here, or that maybe i was thinking too much?

Comment: That's a good start, but I think the "and has a better description or answers." part should be improved further.