# Why is the following question closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions

I am specifically talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19586093/210336).

It's about parsing a string the GMT timezone in it. Initially it was asked as how to parse a time string with any time zone. There was another question asking just that with a solution.

However, because in the scenario of question number 1 the timezone is always GMT, another answer exists that fits that specific scenario better and does not apply to question number 2.

Should question number 1 still be marked as duplicate or not? While the duplicate link does point people to the other answer that also applies, it might also steer people away from the more specific better applicable answer for question number 1?

Imho, the answer to question number 2 can be posted as a link in question number 1 (either as a comment, as another answer or even as an edit to an existing answer) as the ultimate goal should always be future visitors (over the OP).

EDIT: 
This is a near duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51519/139162), however the answer there treats the case of question 2 not answering question 1, while here it actually does, but the new answer to question 1 doesn't answer question 2 but *is* better in the case of question 1.

Comment: Similar ones are not duplicates. If it's the same question in different "skin", then they are duplicates. "Caching" is an answer to a lot of questions but it does not make them all dupes, does it? Now, it seems one of the questions changed meaning a bit, bordering with being a chameleon question, and that's a different issue.

Comment: @Molot, I totally agree. In the case of the specific question I linked it is a closer call. Still I think it is not a duplicate, but it still has been closed as such. I cannot vote te reopen it though.

Comment: Neither can I, so let's see what others will say. Consider [meta-tag:specific-question] on this.

Comment: @Mołot I've added the tag. Should I change the title to something more specific?

Comment: Who am I to tell you what you should do? I only suggested what I thought was good idea. Now everyone will know what you are asking is not a duplicate of more general issue, but specific concern. I hope it'll help. Dunno about the title.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I read the questions:

> Question 1: How can I parse a DateTime-String with the GMT timezone at the end.
>
> Question 2: How can I parse a DateTime-String with a timezone at the end.

The answer to question 2 fits perfectly, I fail to see how they're not duplicates.

> However, because in the scenario of question number 1 the timezone is always GMT, another answer exists that fits that specific scenario better and does not apply to question number 2.

That's true, it's a special edge case which might be worth mentioning in that other answer.

> Should question number 1 still be marked as duplicate or not?

Yes, it should be closed.

> While the duplicate link does point people to the other answer that also applies, it might also steer people away from the more specific better applicable answer for question number 1?

Actually, the answer given to question 1 is an edge case which is not portable and not really well documented, it also breaks the moment you move out of this edge case with no clear hint to why. I consider it inferior to the answer given in question 2, but as I said, it might be worth to be mentioned in that answer or as a separate answer.

Comment: I'd say that GMT is quite common as sort of normalized time. I assume that's why it has the special option of parsing. When storing dates "underwater", you often don't need specific time zone information. Hence I don't agree that it's an edge case. It's not just a coincidence that it's fixed to GMT. I would even go as far as to say that if in this (or a similar) scenario a different time zone would be required, that that would be an edge case. Explicitly building in the flexibility of different time zones seems overkill.

Comment: Not considering the definition of "duplicate", but only looking at future visitors and "making the internet a better place": I'd say that I would more likely be in the fixed GMT case and in that case would prefer to use the answer to question 1 than the answer to question 2.